# How to make shell execute something immediately after user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a task where I need the shell to execute something immediately after user's input.

Example:

```
root@hq> pwd
<my user defined function>
/home/users/home40/spandiya
root@hq>
```

I need my defined function to run immediately after user inputs "pwd", how do i do that? I do not want `PROMPT_COMMAND` which is executed by shell just before PS1.

I need my script to be executed immediately after user input.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Isn't everything executed immediately after user input ?

Comment: What i meant is Just before shell starts to execute the command given by user,i need my defined function to be executed every time.

Comment: Can you put an example in your question please?

Comment: $pwd>

<my function should be executed>

/home/users/spandiya/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work-around using `trap DEBUG`:

```
mycmd() { tty; echo "custom command"; }

trap 'mycmd' DEBUG

$ pwd
/dev/cons0
custom command
/home/user
```

`mycmd` function runs just after user input but before executing user's entered command.

Comment: Anubhav,when do i receive this DEBUG signal,i tired this already this was not working.

Comment: What's not working, provide some details. Above is direct copy paste from terminal.

Comment: I have a situation where the system goes fro reboot immediately if we enter our preparatory command, so i thought of executing this func. immediately after user inputs. Is there any other way i could do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about system reboot event but this `trap` command executes before all the commands that user enters.

Comment: The function that needs to be executed exist in /etc/profile,so i tried placing the below trap command in /etc/profile. 

trap my_func DEBUG

So as i said above if i execute one of our preparatory command system goes for reboot immediately without even leaving time for next prompt to be printed.

Comment: I used `tty` and `echo` just as an example. You can replace them with whatever custom command you have. [See this demo also](http://ideone.com/cHFbPw)

Comment: Please have a look at following o/p

sw0:root> pwd

/root

/dev/ttyS0

+++++++Executing CLI history++++++++++++